# Coverting clauses to CNF

Tags: logic, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

How would I start converting these given clauses:
p ∧ q, p ∧ ¬q, ¬p ∧ q, ¬p ∧ ¬q to CNF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They already are in CNF!

A statement is in CNF if it is a generalized conjunction of generalized disjunctions of literals.  $p$,, $q$, $\neg p$, and $\neg q$ are literals, but each of them can also be seen as a generalized disjunction of literals: there is just 1 disjunct!  And since they are then conjuncted together, it is in CNF.

In general:

Something like $(p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)$ is clearly in CNF, but $(p \lor q) \land \neg p$ is in CNF as well, and so is $q \land \neg p$, and even $q$ by itself is in CNF.  $p \lor q$ is also in CNF: it is a conjunction with a single conjunct, and that conjunct is a disjunction of literals.